# What is the editable data type?

Tags: java, android, arrays

The getText() method returns Editable datatype. Why does it not return integer data type? What is the difference between Editable and Integer data type? I read about the Editable datatype on developers site, but I didn't understand properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a string from an editable:

```
editText.getText().toString();
```

getting an integer from it:

```
Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
```